# Showing Simple Duration timer left on screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Is there any simple way that i can show the time remaing in DURATION on screen?

```
void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details){
        if(state == State.menu){
           timer = Timer(duration = new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
            state = State.playing;
           });
           print("STARTING IN [secondsremaing]");
        }
```

or should i have to make it complex and implement any other class to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will *not* work that way because a [`Timer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) will only call the given callback after the given `Duration`, but it will not **tick** for you.
If you want to show an updated widget indicating the remaining time, you will have to use a ticker and this is normally achieved by setting up an [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html).

In your case, it could look something like this (assuming you are in a `StatefulWidget`):

```dart
class _YourWidgetsState extends State<YourWidget> with SingleTickerProviderMixin {
  AnimationController remainingTimeController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    remainingTimeController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
  }

  /// Used somewhere in your build method.
  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    if(state == State.menu){
      timer = Timer(duration = new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        state = State.playing;
      });
      print("STARTING IN [secondsremaing]");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Obviously return your other widgets in here as well.

    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: remainingTimeController,
      builder: (context, _) => Text('${remainingTimeController.value * 60 * 5}'),
    );
  }
}
```